# CFile Copy Method to fix file access denied issue

Tags: c++, mfc

My app met a ramdon error. the txt file access denied when the new file generated and it's size is 0K.

I just want to copy the existing file and rename it after closed the current one.

Could anyone give me a method to Copy a file? Thanks.

my code snippet as below.

```
ofstream    m_LogFile;

CFile   logcfile;

if(dwLength > 1024*1024*10 )
        {
            string fileDate = status.m_mtime.Format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");        
            string modulePath = Util::GetModulePath();
            string fileNewName(modulePath);
            fileNewName += "mytextlog" + fileDate + ".txt";
            m_LogFile.close();
                           // I want to insert CFile copy method before rename it.
            logcfile.Rename(m_sLogFileName.c_str(), fileNewName.c_str());
            m_LogFile.open(m_sLogFileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
            _findfile(modulePath.c_str());
        }
```

*I assumed that my app error caused by the code above.*

Answer (score 1):

CFile does not have a method to copy a file.

Use the ::CopyFile() function to simply copy a file without any need to open and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes CFile does not have a method to copy file. You could use ::CopyFile Win32 method as posted before, or there is another (little complicated) way with CFile see example at [CFile::Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx) method